# Pandas: reshaping data pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
df =
id test score date
1  A    1     2000-01-01
1  B    3     2000-01-01
1  A    1     2000-01-30
1  B    5     2000-01-30
2  A    2     2000-01-01
2  B    4     2000-01-01
3  A    6     2000-01-01
4  A    2     2000-01-01
```

I want to group_by `id` and `date` in order to get columns containing the type of the test for the same `id` and `date`:

```
df_outcome =
id testA testB date
1  1     3     2000-01-01
1  1     5     2000-01-30
2  2     4     2000-01-01
```

note that individuals 3 and 4 do not have test A and B in the same date and therefore are excluded from the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
(df.pivot(index=["id", "date"], columns="test", values="score")
   .dropna()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .add_prefix("test")
   .reset_index()
   .convert_dtypes())
```

- pivot over id & date with test variables in the column, scores as the content
- NaN will arise if a id-date pair doesn't have A or B score: so drop them
- move the "test" from the name of the columns to be the prefixes of the column names, i.e., testA, testB
- move id & date back to the columns side
- due to possible NaNs, things got floated, so convert datatypes for depromotion if possible, i.e., float to int here

to get

```py
   id        date  testA  testB
0   1  2000-01-01      1      3
1   1  2000-01-30      1      5
2   2  2000-01-01      2      4
```

Comment: great answer Mustafa, I am trying to apply it into a more extensive data and I am getting the error ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. By any means would you know how to solve it?

Comment: thanks. it means that for a given id & date pair, there are more than 1 A scores (or B scores). Is that expected? If expected, how would they be aggregated? There's a solution for it (slight change required only), but the user needs to tell if that's expected and how to move on.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Yes, ideally I would be interested in keeping the first observation per id and date.

Comment: oh okay. then the "mysterious" solution is changing `.pivot` to `.pivot_table`, and passing `aggfunc="first"` argument pair to it along with the existing ones. Can think of `pivot_table` as an extension to handle these duplicacy cases (and some more as seen in the documentation). And `aggfunc`, short for "aggregator function", is telling pandas how to deal such cases. It's to take mean by default, we make it take the first one.